# Failed to start MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

Hello can some one help me. This is the log from `journalctl -xe`

```
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Nov 14 20:13:21 us3r systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 14 20:13:21 us3r systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 14 20:13:21 us3r systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Nov 14 20:13:49 us3r gnome-terminal-[6034]: g_menu_insert_item: assertion 'G_IS_MENU_ITEM (item)' failed
Nov 14 20:14:14 us3r polkitd(authority=local)[1528]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:15542:135941 (system bus name :1.198 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], obj
Nov 14 20:14:17 us3r polkitd(authority=local)[1528]: Operator of unix-session:c2 successfully authenticated as unix-user:dodo to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.freedesktop.syste
Nov 14 20:14:17 us3r polkitd(authority=local)[1528]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:15542:135941 (system bus name :1.198, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authenti
Nov 14 20:14:29 us3r sudo[15552]:     dodo : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start mysqld
Nov 14 20:14:29 us3r sudo[15552]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 14 20:14:29 us3r sudo[15552]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 14 20:14:36 us3r sudo[15560]:     dodo : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start mysqld.service
Nov 14 20:14:36 us3r sudo[15560]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 14 20:14:36 us3r sudo[15560]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 14 20:15:26 us3r sudo[15615]:     dodo : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/apt autoclean
Nov 14 20:15:26 us3r sudo[15615]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 14 20:15:26 us3r sudo[15615]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 14 20:15:31 us3r sudo[15622]:     dodo : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/apt autoremove
Nov 14 20:15:31 us3r sudo[15622]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 14 20:15:32 us3r sudo[15622]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 14 20:17:01 us3r CRON[15773]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 14 20:17:01 us3r CRON[15774]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov 14 20:17:01 us3r CRON[15773]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 14 20:17:27 us3r gvfsd-metadata[4566]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Nov 14 20:17:27 us3r gvfsd-metadata[4566]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Nov 14 20:17:27 us3r gvfsd-metadata[4566]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Nov 14 20:17:27 us3r gvfsd-metadata[4566]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Nov 14 20:17:27 us3r gvfsd-metadata[4566]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Nov 14 20:17:27 us3r gvfsd-metadata[4566]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Nov 14 20:17:27 us3r gvfsd-metadata[4566]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Nov 14 20:17:27 us3r gvfsd-metadata[4566]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Nov 14 20:17:44 us3r polkitd(authority=local)[1528]: Operator of unix-session:c2 successfully authenticated as unix-user:dodo to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.gtk.vfs.file-oper
Nov 14 20:17:44 us3r pkexec[15906]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Nov 14 20:17:44 us3r pkexec[15906]: dodo: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/dodo] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-admin --spawner :1.10 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/1 --address 
Nov 14 20:17:44 us3r kernel: capability: warning: `gvfsd-admin' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
Nov 14 20:17:47 us3r polkitd(authority=local)[1528]: Operator of unix-session:c2 successfully authenticated as unix-user:dodo to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.gtk.vfs.file-oper
Nov 14 20:19:21 us3r gnome-terminal-[6034]: g_menu_insert_item: assertion 'G_IS_MENU_ITEM (item)' failed
```

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-11-14 20:13:21 CET; 5min ago
  Process: 15409 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 15388 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 14 20:13:21 us3r systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 14 20:13:21 us3r systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 14 20:13:21 us3r systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Nov 14 20:13:21 us3r systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 14 20:13:21 us3r systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 14 20:13:21 us3r systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: can you please tell how much RAM does your server has?

Comment: what the mysql log say?